# How can I have a Java class where an instance variable may be of different types?

Tags: java, class

I have a class defined like:

```
public class Test {
  private String a;
  private String b;

  public Test(String a, String b) {
    super();
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

At some point I create instances of this class and put them in a `List<Test>` `ArrayList`. The problem is sometimes I want `a` to be of type `double` not `String` (i.e. Use another constructor in which `a` is a `double`). I'm also interested in always storing the value in a variable called `a` no matter what. This means creating another instance variable of type `double` with a different name will not do. It would not be a problem to just make a new class with an instance variable `a` of type `double` if it wasn't for the fact that the two classes would not be able to go into the same `ArrayList` which is also something I need done.

One thing I've seen that could help is to make a `List<Object>` `ArrayList` which can hold instances of any class, but I think this is considered bad practice. Any ideas on how I could achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Look into Java generics, specifically Java generics for classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could do something with generics, that's probably not what you want. There is no bound on the type parameter `T`, so its type is effectively `Object`. All you can do is print its value and test for equality, you can't use it in an arithmetic expression (if it's a `Double`).

```
public class Test<T> {
    private T a;

    public Test(T a) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
    }
    
    public void doSomething() {
        a.??? // only methods on Object can be called here
    }
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Test<?>> tests = new ArrayList<>();
        tests.add(new Test<String>("foo"));
        tests.add(new Test<Double>(42.0));
    }
}
```

You are probably better off with a type hierarchy, but it depends on what you are actually doing:

```
public interface Test {
    boolean doSomething();

    class TestString implements Test {
        private final String a;

        public TestString(String a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean doSomething() {
            return a.contains("foo");
        }
    }
    
    class TestDouble implements Test {
        private final double a;

        public TestDouble(double a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean doSomething() {
            return a > 10.0;
        }
    }

    static void main(String... args) {
        List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>();
        tests.add(new TestString("foo"));
        tests.add(new TestDouble(42.0));
    }
}
```